# Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '(String)'

Tags: ios, json, swift, string

I'm constructing multipart form-data request. I'm getting build error for append statements

```
var dataBody = Data() 
dataBody.append("--\(boundary + lineBreak)") //Error
```

**Error:**
**Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '(String)'**

It's weird as this works in other project. Am I missing something? How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to append a string to a `Data` object which won't compile , you need to convert this string first to `Data` with proper encoding `.utf8` here like this

```
var dataBody = Data() 
let str = "--\(boundary + lineBreak)"
dataBody.append(Data(str.utf8))
```

Comment: You ninjaed me, so instant +1; I was only going to add: Swift has no way to guess what encoding you want to use to represent your string as data. What looks like an extra hoop to jump through is you providing the additional information that the string should be encoded as UTF-8.

Comment: Tx, seems to work. Why didn't it give error in other project? Both are using swift 5.

Comment: @Raymond sure `dataBody` isn't of type `Data`  there ?

Comment: @Sh_Khan I just copied the exact same code from other project to this new project. Can't figure out why it didn't complain for older project. Does it has to do something with any project/language settings?